# Cannot reset my Windows 11 Laptop

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-v23h2

If I attempt to access Windows settings and navigate to System > Recovery > Reset This PC, everything proceeds as expected until my computer restarts. Upon restarting, it boots up to the advanced boot options page, where the only available action is to input commands through Command Prompt. Attempting to use Start-up Repair results in an error message stating that it is unable to proceed. The only recourse is to click the "Exit And Continue To Windows 11" button, which returns me to the login screen. Upon signing in, I encounter the "There was a problem resetting your PC" error.

I have already attempted to run the System File Checker (SFC) to identify any corrupted files, but it did not detect any issues. Are there any solutions available? I have also tried making a Windows 11 installation drive but it does not seem to detect my NVMe SSD. If additional information is required, please feel free to ask.

Comment: It's impossible that the Windows 11 installation won't detect an NVMe SSD. How are creating the boot media? Try to follow [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: Use the computer manufacturer's (or disk manufacturer's) drive test app to test the SSD for an early failure

Comment: Download a Windows 11 ISO, mount the ISO within Windows, launch setup.exe and when prompted choose the option to keep nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I made my installation media with the "Media Creation Tool" from the Microsoft site itself. I will try out all of these and will let you know for any further changes, I appreciate your responses.

Comment: I tried the method of downloading the windows iso, mounting it, and running setup.exe and I did in fact boot into a fresh windows installation but my ssd storage space is still at 102 out of 208gb free. I am a little bit confused as I set it to keep nothing. I don't think Windows 11 Takes 100gb so does anyone know what is wrong? If you need more information do not hesitate to ask. Thank You.